# megacli cant configure jbod slot num all the same

Tags: hardware-raid, ubuntu-20.04, megacli, jbod

I am trying to add a bunch of JBOD disks to my home server, I have a SAS expanded card and have added 4 x 2TB disks which can be seen as separate devices (37-40); but I can't set them to JBOD using.

```
sudo megacli -PDMakeJbod -PhysDrv[36:0,36:1,36:2,36:3] -a0
```

JBOD is enabled.

It is weird since they are all at slot 0; if I try to put them into Raid 5 it says [36:1] is not a disk, which makes sense since they are all "slot 0"

The 4 new disks are attached to the same 4 x SATA - MiniSAS cable.

Can someone help me out here and point me in the correct direction. This is for my home server so no issues with trying stuff as nothing is depending on this running.

Details:

```
sudo megacli -PDList -aALL | egrep -i "Slot|State|device"
Enclosure Device ID: 36
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 37
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: CC25
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 36
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 38
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: CV22
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 36
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 39
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: CC25
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 36
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 40
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 0A80
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 32
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: TE05
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: Unknown 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Device Id: 33
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: TE05
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: Unknown 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 2
Device Id: 34
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: TE05
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: Unknown 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 3
Device Id: 35
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: U5E0
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
```

Comment: This is a known issue with PMC Sierra expanders that report all slots as zero. Unfortunately with megaraid it is not possible to use device id as key for phy operations, so you should either use a different expander that reports slots appropriately or a different controller that treats equal slots behind expander as directly attached phys and enumerate them by id..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which controller would you recommend?